# How to block access to one page and redirect to another

Tags: html, redirect, restriction

Ok. Here's what I want to do.

Suppose I have three pages: `page1.html`, `page2.html` and `page3.html`.

I want to restrict access to `page2.html` to those whose previous page is `page1.html`. 
In other words, if visitors try to come to `page2.html` from any url other than `page1.html`, I want to redirect them to `page3.html` immediately.

How would I go about doing that, and where would I put the code? I've tried looking up info online, but I can never find any simple and straight-to-the-point answers.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only one question/topic per Question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh"/>`

It makes you change your current URL. Try putting this on `page2.html` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1; url = page3.html" />
</head>
</html>
```

In `content` the first number means how much to wait before redirecting. You can make it like five seconds and add a message saying `acces denied, redirecting in five seconds`.

Comment: Great. That explains how to redirect, but let me spell out what I actually want to do. I want to deny access to page2.html from those who try to get there other than from page1.html. In other words, page1.html should be the only gateway to access page2.html. If they DON'T come from page1.html, I want it to skip to page3.html. What then?